# I'm trying to apply celery to Class based view(apis) in django. How can I do this?

Tags: python, django, api, asynchronous, celery

Is it a correct way to apply celery to class based views?
And, if it is, how can I apply celery to class based Views?
I can’t apply just tagging @app.task above functions inside class.

```
class ScheduleByFranchiseIdView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
permission_classes = (IsAdmin,)
serializer_class = ScheduleSerializer
@app2.task
def get(self, request, franchise_id, start = None, end = None):
    if start != None and end != None:
        query1 = Q(student__profile__franchise__exact=franchise_id)
        query2 = Q(start_time__gte=start)
        query3 = Q(end_time__lt=end)
        queryset = Schedule.objects.filter(query1 & query2 & query3).exclude(status=ScheduleStatus.DELETED).order_by('-id')
        serializer = ScheduleSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    else:
        query1 = Q(student__profile__franchise__exact=franchise_id)
        queryset = Schedule.objects.filter(query1).exclude(status=ScheduleStatus.DELETED).order_by('-id')
        serializer = ScheduleSerializer(queryset, many=True)

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

I'm trying to test this api and when I call HTTP GET Method to call this api,
i get the error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tonyscoding\Desktop\TOCOL\TOCOL_backend\api\testing\test_pagination.py", line 154, in test_admin_schedule_pagination
    response = self.client.get('/api/schedule/by/franchise/simple/1/')
  File "C:\Users\Tonyscoding\Desktop\TOCOL\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\test.py", line 286, in get
    response = super().get(path, data=data, **extra)
  File "C:\Users\Tonyscoding\Desktop\TOCOL\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\test.py", line 203, in get
    return self.generic('GET', path, **r)
  File "C:\Users\Tonyscoding\Desktop\TOCOL\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\test.py", line 232, in generic
    method, path, data, content_type, secure, **extra)
  File "C:\Users\Tonyscoding\Desktop\TOCOL\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 422, in generic
    return self.request(**r)
  File "C:\Users\Tonyscoding\Desktop\TOCOL\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\test.py", line 283, in request
    return super().request(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Tonyscoding\Desktop\TOCOL\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\test.py", line 235, in request
    request = super().request(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Tonyscoding\Desktop\TOCOL\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 503, in request
    raise exc_value
  File "C:\Users\Tonyscoding\Desktop\TOCOL\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Tonyscoding\Desktop\TOCOL\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Tonyscoding\Desktop\TOCOL\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Tonyscoding\Desktop\TOCOL\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Tonyscoding\Desktop\TOCOL\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Tonyscoding\Desktop\TOCOL\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Tonyscoding\Desktop\TOCOL\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Tonyscoding\Desktop\TOCOL\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\Tonyscoding\Desktop\TOCOL\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Tonyscoding\Desktop\TOCOL\venv\lib\site-packages\celery\local.py", line 191, in __call__
    return self._get_current_object()(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Tonyscoding\Desktop\TOCOL\venv\lib\site-packages\celery\app\task.py", line 392, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
```

my celery worker get the task. I think it's not a worker problem..

Comment: What job you've trying to delegate for Celery?

Comment: I am trying to delegate api responses on website to celery. (ex. reading from and writing to db). If it's not a correct way to apply celery to web backend, then what kind of job should I delegate to celery for huge amount of transactions?(I mean, i want to make a lot of website visitors to use my website with pleasant.)

Comment: Please, share some code to understan how you run Celery. Basically, an JSON serializable error will occur when you've trying to pass object instance into Celery task. In that case always use an ID and then get it from DB within task. You might set another serializer - pickle - but it's a security breach.

Comment: I added some code registering task to celery app. what's wrong with it?

Comment: Now it's clear that have chosen wrong place to decorate and wrong workload for Celery. Imagine that it would work, then you would get decrease in performance, because GET placed by Celery in some queue (Rabbit, Redis, etc) what will take a bunch of ms on network operation, then another Celery instance (a worker) does his work on it and place the result back into Redis, and finally you've got it calling `result.get()`.

Comment: Then where should I make a task function??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case might work next scenario. Create a task for hard workload:

```py
@app.task
def schedule_by_franchise(franchise_id, start=None, end=None):
    # Do some slow workload, filtering by non-indexed fields or something.
    if start is not None and end is not None:  # is not None ~20% faster than != None
        query1 = Q(student__profile__franchise__exact=franchise_id)
        query2 = Q(start_time__gte=start)
        query3 = Q(end_time__lt=end)
        queryset = Schedule.objects.filter(query1 & query2 & query3).exclude(status=ScheduleStatus.DELETED).order_by('-id')
    else:
        query1 = Q(student__profile__franchise__exact=franchise_id)
        queryset = Schedule.objects.filter(query1).exclude(status=ScheduleStatus.DELETED).order_by('-id')

    # Returns something serializable and what could be used for more faster DB search (founded object primary keys might fits)
    return tuple(queryset.values_list('id', flat=True))
```

When executed first GET you should create Celery task and then save it TASK_ID somewhere to later get result:

```py
from celery.result import AsyncResult


class ScheduleByFranchiseIdView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAdmin,)
    serializer_class = ScheduleSerializer

    def get(self, request, franchise_id, start=None, end=None, task_id=None):
        if not task_id:
            task = schedule_by_franchise.delay(franchise_id, start, end)
            return Response({
                'task': task.task_id,
                'status': 'processing',
                'message': f'Please, try again in 10 seconds with following task_id={task.task_id}',
            })
        else:
            result = AsyncResult(task_id)
            if result.ready():
                ids = result.result
                queryset = Schedule.objects.filter(id__in=ids)
                serializer = ScheduleSerializer(queryset, many=True)
                return Response(serializer.data)
            else:
                return Response({
                    'status': 'not_ready_yet',
                    'message': 'Please, try again in 5 seconds',
                })
```

Comment: I don't know what to say. You saved my week!!! I'll try it tomorrow. I really appreciate it. Thank u so much!!!!

Comment: I have a question before going to bed. When you said 'do some slow workload' in task, you are saying not to do something like changing password in celery task? Is it bad to do something fast in celery task instead of doing it in viewset class?

Comment: When you need performance you've to answer fast. For faster answers you should try to avoid I/O operations. Fetching URL or doing slow DB queries are the most famous I/O. Saving new password could be relativly fast and not needed in a separate task. You need to measure your app to detect bottlenecks and make an effort to get around them.